# Proving that G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group such that the automorphism $f:G\to G$ sends more than three quarters of elements of G to their inverses. Show that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$ and that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Did you try to show?

Comment: I simply didn't get any clue to start with. Please help.